# Air for Android app is keeping screen awake when not in app

Tags: android, air

I have an air for android app that has event listeners for ACTIVATE and DEACTIVATE, inside the activate I tell the screen to stay awake and in the deactivate I tell it to go back to normal like so :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivateHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activateHandler);

protected function deactivateHandler(event:Event):void{
    SFX.disableSound();
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
}

protected function activateHandler(event:Event):void{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
}
```

But the screen will stay awake at all times even when on the android home screen unless you force close the app... any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using this in your java code:

```
// Gets one of the views visible on the screen and sets keepScreenOn to true.
// This means the screen will stay on as long as the specified view is visible.
this.findViewById(R.id.viewId).setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

Or you could put `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem. My app was able to keep the screen on by setting systemIdleMode to SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE, and it would force the screen to stay on. However, when the app tried to set the systemIdleMode back to SystemIdleMode.NORMAL, so the screen could turn off, the screen was still staying on.

What turned out to be the problem in my case is was a missing android permission. I had already added this permission to my app XML file, so that i could use the keep-alive function:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`

Turns out this is not the only permission you need. I added this permission also:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>`

And suddenly my app was able to let the screen be turned off again.